# How to debug an exe with multiple dlls using breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have a `myapp.exe` that after some complicated logic is run by another program. I wanted to debug the issues with `myapp.exe` just like visual studio preferably using breakpoints. What is the way to achieve this? The exe is a console application and is run on the spot. It's not a running process so I cant attach a debugger.

The expected behavior I would want is:

- Do magic and set breakpoints for that exe and dlls
- Call the exe from the other program
- Visual studio hits the breakpoint and I can debug what is going on

Comment: Good question and great work for realising you need to get good at debugging to get to the next step of programming mastery. Honestly, put a break point (F9) in the function causing you problem and then step through the code (F11). You should watch a short YouTube video on the topic to work out how to use the Immediate Window, Call Stack Window, Watch Window and how to Edit & Continue and drag/drop the code control (yellow line) to skip lines up or down.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` where you want to attach the debugger. You can place it just before your desired breakpoint location. Windows will ask you what debugger do you want to attach.

Another way is to check the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached property and wait for the debugger like this (polling):

```
while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

The application will loop until you attach the debugger (in visual studio via attach to process command, Ctrl+alt+P ).
Again, just place a break point after or even in the loop and you're done.

This is a well know way used to debug a windows service application and can be useful also for your intent.